# Bash holding onto lock of usb drive, bug?

Tags: filesystems, usb, usb-drive

I notice that bash seems to want to hold locks on my Truecrypt USB drive that has been accessed, even when no access process is actually occurring.

When I try to mount the drive I get various "device is busy" errors. When I run `fuser`, it identifies bash as the culprit. So, annoyingly enough I go quit the shell or shells I have open. Then try again and the device dismounts correctly.

This would appear to be some kind of bug. There is no "buffered information" involved. For example, I can come in the morning after my shell has been sitting idle for 10 hours, try to dismount the drive and it will fail even though the last interaction I had with the drive was a copy over 10 hours ago.

Is this a bug or should I be doing some additional kind of configuration to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Did you `cd` any `bash` process into the mounted directory?

Comment: Yes, but I left again.